# Install PHPMailer in directory other than project root

Tags: php, composer-php, phpmailer

I want to install composer and PHPMailer in a directory other than my project root directory, since I want to be using it across projects.

My project is in some subfolders in `~/var/www/html/...`
When I install composer and PHPMailer to `~/var/www/`, my php script can't seem to be able to include the `autoload.php` file:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
echo "1";
require '~/var/www/vendor/autoload.php';
echo "2"; // it doesn't get here
```

When installing it to the same directory as the php file's, it does work.
(using `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `../../vendor/autoload.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is '~' symbol which means home directory. PHP is usually run under www-data user which doesn't have any home directory.

So you need to provide either a full path starting with '/' or a path relative to your project.